# Prime sign ` followed by numerical values

Tags: numerics, numerical-value

Here are 2 lines of the numerical output of Mathematica:
-0.00210552112879451522825757575757575758`12.493743372412704 0.02820981709630175825378787878787878789`13.228355515542138

What does the prime sign ` mean here?
When I copy each line of number back to the Mathematica script,
the stuff after the prime sign disappears.
e.g.

-0.00210552112879451522825757575757575758`12.493743372412704

becomes just

-0.00210552112879451522825757575757575758

Comment: Start here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html . In particular, the section on _Numerical Precision_ and the chart titled _Input forms for numbers_.

Comment: BTW, generally the sign for a "prime" is a forward tick, `'`.  The back tick is used to denote precision, accuracy (as in ```0``2.3```), and contexts.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.